# Angular / HTML clear input events

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am working on an Angular app and I seem to have stumbled upon a small bug/problem. I have 4 clickable areas in my html and each click calls a function of the component's .ts script. So far, so good. I want to make each area only be clickable once, however this doesn't seem to work the way I am doing it (and I do not quite understand why).

```
clicked(event: Event): void {

// Get coordinates of clicked cell
var elementId: string = (event.target as Element).id;

if(this.answersGiven.includes(elementId)) {
  console.log("included");
  return;
}

this.answersGiven.push(elementId);
```

And the html

```
       <table>
        <tr>
        <td id="A1" (click)="clicked($event);">
       </tr>
```

So after the first click, the answer should be pushed into the array which is working just fine. However after the second click on the same cell it is not jumping into the if condition. When clicking a third time on the same cell, it works however. When i log the events, the second time I only get "" instead of the element id. My guess is that this could have something to do with some sort of buffer or that the button is pushed down and stays down but I couldn't find anything realted to that.

Glad for any help, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td (click)="clicked($event, 'A1');">
</tr>
```

TS:

```
clicked(event: Event, cod: string): void {

// Get coordinates of clicked cell
var elementId: string = (event.target as Element).id;

if(this.answersGiven.includes(cod)) {
  console.log("included");
  return;
}

this.answersGiven.push(cod);
```

the Angular way of build your HTML have probably changed your `<td id="A1"`, check into your browser developer tool if the ID keeps the same.

Comment: Yes this works, the Id is "" the second time. But when I click a third time the corred id is given again. I have no idea why this happens, though.

Comment: If you could create a stackblitz for more details. I dont get what is happening. :(